# MySQL - How use SUM() and exclude the SUM() results that is = 0

Tags: mysql

I want to display results of SUM() where the result is not 0 (zero)

MySQL Table Name:

- `memberlist`

Columns:

- `m_username`
- `2021_03_24`
- `2021_03_17`
- `2021_03_10`
- `2021_03_03`
- `2021_02_24`
- `2021_02_17`

MySQL Query:

```
SELECT *, SUM( IFNULL(2021_03_24, 0) + IFNULL(2021_03_17, 0) + IFNULL(2021_03_10, 0) + IFNULL(2021_03_03, 0) + IFNULL(2021_02_24, 0) + IFNULL(2021_02_17, 0) ) AS TOTAL_CONTRIBUTION FROM memberlist GROUP BY m_username ORDER BY TOTAL_CONTRIBUTION DESC`
```

Problem with above MYSQL Query:

```
It shows results where `TOTAL_CONTRIBUTION` = 0
```

How do I modify my MySQL query so that the results EXCLUDE any data where `TOTAL_CONTRIBUTION` = 0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried adding a HAVING clause?

```
SELECT *, 
SUM( 
   IFNULL(2021_03_24, 0) 
 + IFNULL(2021_03_17, 0) 
 + IFNULL(2021_03_10, 0) 
 + IFNULL(2021_03_03, 0) 
 + IFNULL(2021_02_24, 0) 
 + IFNULL(2021_02_17, 0) 
 ) AS TOTAL_CONTRIBUTION
FROM memberlist
GROUP BY m_username 
HAVING TOTAL_CONTRIBUTION!=0  
ORDER BY TOTAL_CONTRIBUTION 
DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
GROUP BY m_username having TOTAL_CONTRIBUTION > 0
```

Comment: I don't think you can use Aliases in the Having clause...

Comment: @Ankit Bajpai  you certainly can't use in a where clause but you can in a having clause (I think I'll double check)

Comment: @Ankit Bajpai SELECT COUNT(col1) AS col2 FROM t GROUP BY col2 HAVING col2 = 2; quote from https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html

Comment: I just cross-checked and MySQL allows aliases to be used in Having clause. https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/50391/why-does-mysql-allow-having-to-use-select-aliases. I have updated my query also accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You need a simple HAVING clause -

```
SELECT *, SUM( IFNULL(2021_03_24, 0) + IFNULL(2021_03_17, 0) + IFNULL(2021_03_10, 0) + IFNULL(2021_03_03, 0) + IFNULL(2021_02_24, 0) + IFNULL(2021_02_17, 0) ) AS TOTAL_CONTRIBUTION
  FROM memberlist
 GROUP BY m_username
HAVING TOTAL_CONTRIBUTION > 0
 ORDER BY TOTAL_CONTRIBUTION DESC
```